# Unit Testing Unit of Work and Generic Repository Pattern framework using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am unit testing a Service which is using the a Unit of Work and Generic Repository using Moq. The problem is that in the service class the _subsiteRepository is always null when I run the test in debug mode.

The setup of the Service Class I am mocking

```
private readonly IRepository<Subsite> _subsiteRepository;

public PlatformService(IUnitOfWork<PlatformContext> unitOfWork)
{
    _subsiteRepository = unitOfWork.GetRepository<Subsite>();
}
```

and the method in this class that am testing. The problem is that _subsiteRepository is always null. The method does more than this but this is the relevant part.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Subsite>> GetSubsites()
{
    // Get Subsites
    var subsites = await _subsiteRepository
        .GetAll()
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Finally this is the test I am running:

```
private readonly Mock<IRepository<Subsite>> _subsiteRepository;
private readonly Mock<IUnitOfWork<PlatformContext>> _unitOfWork;
private readonly PlatformService _platformService;

_subsiteRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Subsite>>();
_unitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork<PlatformContext>>();
_platformService = new PlatformService(_unitOfWork.Object);

// Arrange
var fakeSubsites = new List<Subsite>
{
    new Subsite {IDSubsite = new Guid(), Title = "Subsite One"}
}.AsQueryable();

_unitOfWork.Setup(x => x.GetRepository<Subsite>()).Returns(_subsiteRepository.Object);
_unitOfWork.Setup(x => x.GetRepository<Subsite>().GetAll()).Returns(fakeSubsites);

// Act
var subsites = await _platformService.GetSubsites(null, null);

// Assert
Assert.NotNull(subsites);
```

Comment: You setup `unitOfWork.GetRepository` after you have already created the `PlatformService`. Therefore you'll never actually get the `subsiteRepository.Object` within the constructor of the `PlatformService`. I would move the construction of the `PlatformService` just before you need to call the object i.e. just before the `Act`.

Comment: Not exactly related, but is there any reason why you don't just `Mock<ISubsite>` I assume there is an interface for the repository

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move creation of the `_platformService` after Arrange step. Because you call the `PlatformService` constructor before `unitOfWork` mock is setup.

```
_subsiteRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Subsite>>();
_unitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork<PlatformContext>>();

// Arrange
var fakeSubsites = new List<Subsite>
{
    new Subsite {IDSubsite = new Guid(), Title = "Subsite One"}
}.AsQueryable();

_unitOfWork.Setup(x => x.GetRepository<Subsite>()).Returns(_subsiteRepository.Object);
_unitOfWork.Setup(x => x.GetRepository<Subsite>().GetAll()).Returns(fakeSubsites);

// Act
_platformService = new PlatformService(_unitOfWork.Object);
var subsites = await _platformService.GetSubsites(null, null);

// Assert
Assert.NotNull(subsites);
```

Comment: I agree wholly with the first part of your answer, but I disagree with your second part. Yes they are attempting to test two different parts at once but unit testing should not influence your code directly therefore you shouldn't need to add to your business logic only for use in testing. I would recommend that it is possible they consider a method of simply providing a `Subsite` instead of using `IUnitOfWork<T>` as a Service Locator anti-pattern, therefore covering your second point of removing the dependency on mocking the `IUnitOfWork<T>`

Comment: @StephenRoss I removed the second part, because I think it is opinion based and it doesn't provide an answer to the question that user has. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Thank you! I fundamentally misunderstood how moq works. Thanks for the comments on splitting up unit tests too. I will certainly look into how to separate it out cleanly and test one thing at a time.